# Sitting in the middle on a one-way route on the rope-way

Tags: sequences-and-series

While moving up on the rope-way, I noticed that the seat place in the opposite direction was numbered as 95. behind it was number 0, then 1, 2 and so on. my seat place was numbered as 66. what number should i meet when i am in the middle of my one-way route?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I'm lost even on how to try this.  Any points in this direction would be useful.

Comment: Try with just 10 chairs.... and draw a picture.

Comment: Is the answer 19? Thank you for your suggestion to draw the picture. When the 66 chair/car was facing 95, that means it would have been on 34th position (assuming each rope has 48 chairs/cars at a time. So moving 10 positions would mean 20 chair movement.  That means 19th chair would be opposite in the middle of 66.

Comment: The answer is 18.  I was mistaken previously as 19.  

Solution
Total Number of chairs/cars: `96` (in the question chairs are numbered 0 - 95)
If `66` has to be in the middle, then it should occupy 23th position.  That means there will be `24 chairs/car` on my side of rope-way and 24 chairs/cars before the opposite car.  That means there are  in total there will 48 chairs/cars behind 66.  So `66-48 = 18`  18th chair is that I meet when I'm in the middle.  @david-g-stork